# R: Send text messages without the use of 3rd parties (or do it WITH your own number)

Tags: r, sms

I'm trying to use `R` to send text messages - without using platforms like Twilio or Plivo. Is there an easy way to do this in `R`?

The platforms mentioned above make it easy to send text messages, but you have to get verification of the phone numbers / pay for a new number / jump through several hoops. I don't mind paying a small amount, either, but I do want to use my own number. Here's the set up for Twilio:

```
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_SID = "xxxxxxx...")
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_TOKEN = "xxxxxxx...")

my_phone <- "xxxxxxxxxx" # personal phone number / or number you want to send messages to
twilios_phone <- "xxxxxxxxxx" # the number they give you

tw_send_message(from = twilios_phone, to = my_phone, 
                body = "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union")
```

I can send messages to my own phone number, but I *cannot* send anything **from** my own number, which is the point of me asking this question.

The Plivo setup:

```
AUTH_ID = "xxxxx..."
AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxx......."

message <- "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union"

url = "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/xxxxxxx..../Message/"

POST(url, authenticate(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN), 
     body = list(src = "xxxx..", dst = "xx....", 
                 text = message))
```

Both super simple setups, but how can I send messages (free or not) from MY own number, and do it easily? (And yes, I'm doing this to learn/ spam my friends with the Constitution once a month - a worthy cause, I know).

Comment: Look up "adb shell service call"

Comment: Would sending a message text from your email (outlook) do the trick? Your name and email would be in the message you are sending.

Comment: That would work I guess. Not as simple, but yeah

Comment: You should directly ask @Ben_Bolker